# Is Blender suitable for this project?

Tags: animation

Can the community help to know if Blender is suitable for my project. I'm looking to create a 3d shape of xyz vector components that oscillate in size out of phase. The phase shift between vectors to initially be 120degrees but with the potential for varying. The ultimate goal is to get a probability distribution vector for each axis.

Comment: Is there an element of randomness to this varying scale, or is it predetermined by keyframes?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, but, from what I understand, Blender seems like a suitable tool for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in the current form, this question isn't (quite) topical.

Comment: The variation would be regular cyclic, as a stranger to Blender I dont know what keyframes are!. GiantCowFilms show a very unhelpfull attitude to newbies. I vote to close GiantCowFilms!

Comment: OP is asking if Blender is capable to achieve a certain operation he needs to achieve, I don't see how this is off topic, I vote to keep it open, but I'm flagging his response as rude or offensive, please read the rules carefully @user36138

Comment: This communities response to my question has in part been very exclusive - the requirement to reword to fit rules is narrow and off-putting to newbies. Attitudes are precious and elitist. The phrase 'stuffed shirts' comes to mind. Some responders have given me hope that this package is capable of achieving my goals - I thank them.

Answer (score 2):

I think Blender is perfect for your project, you can do all the math with [Python](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/python_console.html), and if you don't know the language it's [very easy to learn](http://www.sololearn.com/Course/Python/), even if you don't have programming experience before because it doesn't have a complex syntaxis.

If you don't want to use code for it or it isn't as complicated then I think Blender is still the best choice because you can easily transform an object an exact number of degrees and come back to change that number as many times as you want, and the graph window for the animation curves has also great tools. Also, if you need some measurements that you can't get with vanilla Blender, I bet you can easily find an addon that does that.

Also, it's free and has extensive [documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/).

Comment: Thanks thats helpfull - it looks like itwill be worthwhile to learn a new package